# What are advantages of predefining variable in global scope?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, jslint, jshint

Often I come in a situation where I act according to my mood:

**Situation A):**

```
 function a() {
     var msg = 'a()';
     ..operate on msg
   }

   function b() {
     var msg = 'b()';
     ..operate on msg
   }
```

**Situation B):**

```
var msg;
function a() {
  msg = 'a()';
 ..operate on msg
}

function b() {
  msg = 'b()';
 ..operate on msg
}
```

Note that with ***"operate on msg"*** I do not mean a function but a bunch of operations.

I am interesting in this because ***JSHint*** points out variables as already predefined despite the fact that they have the same name but appear in different functions for example.

**UPDATE:**
I may have been incorrect when asking this so to clear out the situation I have changed the functions.

**UPDATE 2**
I understand scope. I mean is there any other advantages of one over the other despite the scope?

Comment: it is not different closures.

Comment: It's called variable hoisting:
http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: @tracevipin I have replaced it with "functions". if I have two functions which define the same variable name, linters get angry

Comment: @lukas.pukenis Following the first version of this question, I doubt you fully understood scoping in JavaScript.

Comment: @Sirko, apologies for poor presentation of my question. I have no problem with scoping. My main concern is refactoring big ugly JS files with a lot of functions, if statements where the same variable names are used over and over again :)

Comment: have a small  piece of real code that jshint doesn't like?

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested you must read more about variable hoisting in Javascript.
I will try to demonstrate it.

```
function test() {

    var t1 = msg + " hello";  
    console.log(t1); // prints "undefined hello" because msg is undefined
    var t2 = msgx + " hello"; // msgx ReferenceError

    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    if (a > b) {
        var msg = 'sample';
    }

}

test();
```

Here in the example you can see that `msg` is declared. but it is undefined. On the other hand `msgx` causes reference error. It is not declared anywhere. So the point is the statement `var msg = 'sample';` which comes later in the function inside `if` braces makes `msg` a valid variable everywhere in the function. So again declaring `msg` will give you predefined variable warning.

In javascript only a function can create a scope. Everything declared  in a function will be available in the whole function scope even though there are inner braces of other control statements. All the variables declared in different lines inside a function will be hoisted and treated as if declared in the starting line of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is nearly no difference ... in each case the variable is defined but in case you won't use msg variable first case would be little bit data-saving :) But this is too simple task.

Comment: Yes, optimisation here is non existing, however I have quite a bunch of files I need to refactor with A LOT OF functions, if statements all of them defining the same names over and over again :)

Comment: I see ... well if you are using that global in multiple cases you have to initialize it for each case...in case of no reinitialization, you could use wrong data and cause logical mistake ...

Comment: I think the same and though maybe there are more cases to consider. Anyway thanks for the insight! :)

Comment: In general globals are good for some global flags ... It could be maybe good for your case, but as I said, you have to watch if you are using good data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand scope?

In situation B, your variables are only available within the scope of the function.

```
function(){
    var foo = 10;
}
console.log(foo); //undefined
```

In situation A your variables are available globally.

```
var foo;
function(){
    foo = 10;
}
console.log(foo); //10
```

In situation A, modifying foo from within the function modifies it everywhere. In situation B, only the local variable is modified.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it but I understand scopes. I understand how it works, but when refactoring, I have big files consisting of a lot of functions which uses the same variable names over and over again. That was the reasoning behind my question